# Transition component doesn't work with v-if before slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

i try add  im my tree view component, but, not work
i read the documentation, but, my use case is more especific, and i didn't find anything for this case.
use v-if before the slot, is specific for my personalized tree view.

i try like this:

```
    <Transition name="slide-fade" appear>
        <div v-if="isOpen">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </Transition>
```

i try

```
`       <Transition name="slide-fade" appear>
            <div v-if="$slots.default">
                <div v-if="isOpen">
                    <slot></slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Transition>`
```

but i get the same result, doens't work.
this my setup:

```
    <script lang="ts">
import { ref, Ref, watchEffect } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: 'Folder',
  props: {
    folderName: String,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const isOpen: Ref<boolean> = ref(true);

    const toggleOpen = () => {
      isOpen.value = !isOpen.value;
    };

    return {
      isOpen,
      toggleOpen,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

and my css:

```
    <style scoped>
ul, li, details, summary{
    list-style: none;
}
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
}

.slide-fade-enter-from,
.slide-fade-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(20px);
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Consider adding a [playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/) to your question, where the behavior can be observed

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and I've copied it to one of my projects, everything is fine for me and the transition worked fine. Please check if you're calling the method correctly and make sure you write the css code inside the component because it's **scoped** styles.

This is the components I've made:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-btn @click="toggleOpen">toggle</v-btn>
        <Transition name="slide-fade" appear>
            <div v-if="isOpen">
                <slot></slot>
            </div>
        </Transition>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref, Ref, watchEffect } from "vue";

export default {
    name: "Folder",
    props: {
        folderName: String,
    },
    setup(props) {
        const isOpen: Ref<boolean> = ref(true);

        const toggleOpen = () => {
            isOpen.value = !isOpen.value;
        };

        return {
            isOpen,
            toggleOpen,
        };
    },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
ul,
li,
details,
summary {
    list-style: none;
}

.slide-fade-enter-active {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.slide-fade-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
}

.slide-fade-enter-from,
.slide-fade-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(20px);
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

And this is were I'm using the component:

```
<TestComponent>Hello world!</TestComponent>
```